# Searching inside enum

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum which contains a collection of Strings mapped to names and integers. I would like to return the integers based on the String inside the enum.

I am using the enum for some other purposes as well so I would like to keep it (otherwise I would just use HashMap for this purpose). Is it even possible?

This is an example demonstrating what I would like to achieve

```
public enum Types {

 A("a.micro", 1), B("b.small", 2), C("c.medium", 4);

private String type;
  private int size;

  private Type(String type, int size) {
    this.type = type;
    this.size = size;
  }

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public int getSize() {
    return size;
  }
}
```

I would like to return the size based on the type:

```
Type.valueOf("a.micro").getSize();
```

Comment: There is values() method in enum that allow iterate through values exists in enum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a global hashmap under the `Types` class which stores the relation between the type strings and their corresponding enum instances.

```
private static final Map<String, Types> typeMap = new HashMap<String, Types>();
static {
    for (Types types : values()) {
        typeMap.put(types.type, types);
    }
}

public static Types searchByType(String type) {
    return typeMap.get(type);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
public static int sizeFor(String name) {
    for(Types type : Types.values()) {
        if(type.getType().equals(name)) {
            return type.getSize();
        }
    }
    // handle invalid name
    return 0;
}
```

Other option would be to add a `private static Map<String, Integer> sizes = new HashMap<>();` inside `Types` and `put` mappings inside the constructor. Then the `sizeFor(String)` would just make a simple lookup.

```
private static Map<String, Integer> sizes = new HashMap<>();

Type(String type, int size) {
    this.type = type;
    this.size = size;
    sizes.put(type, size);
}

public static int sizeFor(String name) {
    // Modify if you need to handle missing names differently
    return sizes.containsKey(name) ? sizes.get(name) : 0;
}
```

Since `type` is a custom member variable there are no in-built functions for them. The only in-built functions to get `Types` instances are `valueOf` for name (i.e. you need to pass `"A"` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum Type {

    A("a.micro", 1), B("b.small", 2), C("c.medium", 4);

    private static final Map<String, Type> map = createMap();

    private static Map<String, Type> createMap() {
        Map<String, Type> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Type type : values()) {
            result.put(type.type, type);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String type;
    private int size;

    private Type(String type, int size) {
        this.type = type;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public static Type getForType(String type) {
        return map.get(type);
    }
}
```

Then, just call: `Types.getForType("a.micro").getSize();`